# Colouring dataframe in Rstudio if values are equal to a previous column

Tags: r, dataframe, colors

[image]

Hi,

i have a dataframe with an indicator column and i would like to colour the dataframe, so that if any values equal to the value in that specific row from the indicator column, gets coloured. (example in the picture above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `View()` function is not meant to allow for any kind of formatting, but you can use other tools, like `knitr::kable()` and functions from `kableExtra`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(indicator = rep(1, 5),
                 b2 = rep(3, 5),
                 b3 = rep(1, 5), 
                 b4 = rep(3, 5), 
                 b5 = rep(1, 5))

df |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("b"), ~ cell_spec(.x, background = ifelse(.x == indicator, "red", "white"), color = ifelse(.x == indicator, "white", "black")))) |>
  kable(escape = FALSE) |> 
  kable_styling()
```

[image]