# How to colour or highlight a specifics cell?

Tags: r, colors, background-color, highlight

I have a tibble looks like this (here I used snipping tool to select and highlight)

[image]

I want to colour the values or highlight the values in cells (1,3), (1,9), (3,3), (4,7), (4,8) and so on. How can I do this in R?

Thank you.

Edition: I tried colouring as

```
my_df[1,1] = cell_spec(my_df[1,1], color = 'red')
kbl(my_df[1:10,]) %>%
  kable_paper("striped", full_width = F)
```

but I got this message (it's a long text, I truncated it): `<span style=" color: red !important;" >&lt;span style=&quot; color: red !important;&quot; &gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;`

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colouring dataframe in Rstudio if values are equal to a previous column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73737494/colouring-dataframe-in-rstudio-if-values-are-equal-to-a-previous-column)

Comment: I don't think so. That's about colouring based on conditions whereas I need to colour specific positions.

Comment: I'd suggest creating another set of columns with logicals indicating whether you want that particular cell highlighted or not, and then use the answer given there to apply the highlighting on the created conditions.

Comment: My case is a bit different. I'm testing techniques handling missing values. I randomly replace some values by NA values, fill those NA values using the techniques and make a comparison. And I want to colour or highlight the results.

Comment: I understand - I'm suggesting that you have another set of variables (call it `color_na`, `clarity_na`, etc.) populated with logicals indicating if the value was imputed (TRUE) or not (FALSE), and then use that condition to highlight the actual values.

Answer (score 1):

To complement what I meant in my comments. Here I'm randomly selecting values to highlight using `rbinom()`, you just need to manually set whether a particular value should be `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on whether that value was imputed or not.

The one tedious aspect is applying the `cell_spec()` across the columns. I tried to do so dynamically using `across()`, but I had difficulty doing so. Perhaps someone would find a more functional method.

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

data("diamonds", package = "ggplot2")

df <- head(diamonds)

df <- df |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(across(color:z, ~ if_else(rbinom(1, 1, 0.5) == 1, TRUE, FALSE), .names = "{.col}_na")) |> 
  ungroup()

df |> 
  mutate(color = cell_spec(color, background = if_else(color_na, "red", "white"), 
                           color = if_else(color_na, "white", "black")),
         clarity = cell_spec(clarity, background = if_else(clarity_na, "red", "white"), 
                             color = if_else(clarity_na, "white", "black")),
         depth = cell_spec(depth, background = if_else(depth_na, "red", "white"), 
                             color = if_else(depth_na, "white", "black")),
         table = cell_spec(table, background = if_else(table_na, "red", "white"), 
                           color = if_else(table_na, "white", "black")),
         price = cell_spec(price, background = if_else(price_na, "red", "white"), 
                           color = if_else(price_na, "white", "black")),
         x = cell_spec(x, background = if_else(x_na, "red", "white"), 
                       color = if_else(x_na, "white", "black")),
         y = cell_spec(y, background = if_else(y_na, "red", "white"), 
                       color = if_else(y_na, "white", "black")),
         z = cell_spec(z, background = if_else(z_na, "red", "white"), 
                       color = if_else(z_na, "white", "black"))
         ) |>
  select(-ends_with("na")) |> 
  kable(escape = FALSE) |>
  kable_styling()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Phil! I understand your idea and I'm trying to set values to True or False based on their positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extraKable` and `cell_spec` function to define a rule for formatting. See more in the vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

Comment: I tried colouring as the edition part in my post (I edited it) but I haven't made it. What could be wrong?